# Generic orders URL

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there a way to create a page that requires the user to log in and then shows them all their orders, but only the orders of the logged in user. I need it to the same URL for all users as an external source, that knows noting about the user accounts, will be directing them to it. Currently I see urls like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/drupal/user/142/orders
```

but I want a url like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/drupal/orders
```

And since I've already customised the view of the Orders screen I'd really like to re-use that view, just place it on a generic url. If a non-logged in user tries to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/drupal/user/142/orders` they get told the page doesn't exist rather than told to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have appropriate access control on your custom View, then use something like the [Redirect 403 to User Login](https://drupal.org/project/r4032login) module so customers are returned to your /orders URL after logging in.